# Laravel distinct not doing its job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I have a simple query like this:

```
    if (Cache::has('films')) {
        $films = Cache::get('films', function () {
            return $films = Film::distinct('date')
                ->select('date')
                ->with('entities')
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->get();
        });
        $film = Cache::get('films', function () {
            return Film::select('date')->first();
        });
        dd($films);
```

I am using redis cache, however it looks like, distinct doesn't work for it. As if I do a query without the cache it seems to work fine. Anyone else had that issue? I get everything in the cache, while I should be getting every different date, so 7 results

Comment: Did you try to use distinct without any parameter? (without 'date')

Answer (score 0):

As your code are working without cache closure. It means that you forgot to configure database info (Database username, password etc) in Redis server.